# jQuery print element problem

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to print a div that is currently visible but my jQuery isn't working properly

Here's what I'm trying using the [printElement plugin](http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/)

```
$('.printDirections').click(function() {

    $(this).parent().children().('div').is(':visible').printElement()

});
```

And my HTML looks like this

```
<div class="directionstext">

    <img src="/images/opendays/print.gif" class="printDirections">

    <div id="prop1" style="display: none;">

        some text

    </div>

    <div id="prop2" style="display: none;">

        some text

    </div>

    <div id="prop3" style="display: block;">

        some text

    </div>

</div>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your selector is incorrect. You're probably looking for:

```
$('.printDirections').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('div:visible').printElement();
});
```

Comment: Thanks knew it would be something simple!

Comment: In jQuery, the `is()` method returns a boolean. Once you invoke it, the method chain is broken. http://docs.jquery.com/Is